# select row lowest values using two matrices

Tags: r

If I have this matrix (`mat`):

```
set.seed(140213)
mat <- matrix(runif(16,0,1),nrow = 4)
colnames(mat) <- 1:4
rownames(mat) <- 5:8
#> mat
#          1          2         3         4
#5 0.1120015 0.01454408 0.3411633 0.3456254
#6 0.5709174 0.70443202 0.9114756 0.9157580
#7 0.1500032 0.40889119 0.6231543 0.9736331
#8 0.9773827 0.45136413 0.9706694 0.5022132
```

I can get the of the two *lowest* columns with for each row with:

```
namesmat <- t(apply(mat, 1, function(x)
                            head(names(x)[order(x, decreasing = FALSE)], 2)))

#  [,1] [,2]
#5 "2"  "1" 
#6 "1"  "2" 
#7 "1"  "2" 
#8 "2"  "4"
```

Now my question is:

If I have another matrix (`mat2`)

```
 set.seed(14022013) ; mat2 <- matrix(runif(16,0,1),nrow = 4)
```

How can I get the *lowest* two rows for each column as I did before for `mat2` but ignoring the columns I already selected from `mat`.

E.g. If in `mat2` the highest columns for row `5` were `cols 3 & 1` but would have to choose the nest highest. If the next highest was 'col 2' I would have to choose the next highest. Let me know if this is unclear.

My head wants to to some sort of paried apply using `mat2` and `namesmat` like:

```
 t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) head(
     names(x)[order(x[! names(x) == apply(namesmat,1,c)] ,
         decreasing = FALSE)], 2)))
```

I will be doing this over many mats so that. `mat2` selection depends on the `mat` selection. Then I wil have a `mat3` and the selection of lowest columns per row will depend on the selection of `mat` and `mat2` cobined, so ignoring all rows already selected for `mat` and `mat2` continuing on for several mats.

Obviously in this case there are only 4 columns so i can only do this sequence twice.

Comment: For mat2, do you want the highest two rows for each column or the highest two columns for each row ?

Comment: Just a thought, maybe I misunderstood the question - can't you, after you detected the columns from `mat`, remove those columns  row-wise from `mat2` and then apply the same method again? And btw - do small values correspond in your example to highest columns? You write out the column numbers with the two smallest values.

Comment: @DanielFischer & Juba, sorry for the highest lowest confusion. I meant lowest. I hope my edit is clearer. I am afraid I am not sure how you mean to remove them rowise for each individual row.

Answer (score 0):

May be bit convoluted, but gets work done. I have used simpler matrices to demonstrate whats going on..

```
> mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1), nrow=2 , byrow=T)

> mat2 <- matrix(c(5,6,7,8,8,7,6,5), nrow=2 , byrow=T)

> colnames(mat1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

> colnames(mat2) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

> mat1
     A B C D
[1,] 1 2 3 4
[2,] 4 3 2 1

> mat2 
     A B C D
[1,] 5 6 7 8
[2,] 8 7 6 5

> mymax <- function(x) {
+     names(  x[order(x)]  )[1:2] 
+ }

> mymax2 <- function(x,y) {
+     z <- names(  x[order(x)]  )
+     z[!z %in% y][1:2] 
+ }

> namesmat <- t(apply(mat1, 1, mymax))

> namesmat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "D"  "C" 

> namesmat2 <- t(sapply(1:nrow(mat2), function(i) mymax2(mat2[i,], namesmat[i,])))

> namesmat2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "C"  "D" 
[2,] "B"  "A"
```